# Can Maven help in modifying dependencies, change them and package them back?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

My task is this:

- Take a dependency, which is a zip
- Unpack the dependency
- Run some Java code, add some new files
- Assemble the dependency back, including the new files
- After assembly, build it as another artifact.

My queries:

1. The dependency coordinates need to be provided dynamically during build time. Am looking for something like SystemProperty, but not sure how to take them through my pom.
2. Unpacking is straightforward. unpack-dependencies is all I need.
3. Running Java code - Here's a hiccup again. This project doesn't produce a jar or a war, it's got to be a pom packaging. SO I cannot compile code in the project. I can use the compiler plugin with Java execution. Not sure it's a good practice.
4. Not a problem to assemble, if I can get uptill here.

Any suggestions for points 1 and 3?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the last bullet of your tasks, "after assembly . . . " -- what are you doing when you need to change the assembly's name?  I think you are building another artifact, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Edited the statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alot of the problems with Maven arise from the decision about which build "tasks" translate into discrete Maven builds.  The general idea is that each jar, zip, or whatever your building should get it's own mave build ( aka pom, aka module ).  Looking at your bullets, I believe you have three maven builds, i.e. three poms.

1) The first pom will build your Java utility, i.e. jar.  This jar then becomes a dependency of your other build that needs to execute it as part of the zip assembly process.

2) The second pom will do build the zip.  ( I guess you will actually build several different ones; most likely these are then separate poms -- while you can have a single build produce more than one artifact, leveraging the concept of attached artifacts and classifiers, it's an unnecessary complication that should be avoided unless you *know* you need it. ) These zip assembly poms unzip the primary zip, massage the content via the java util( running the jar via maven-exec plugin), and reassembles the zip.

3) If you need to change the name of an artifact ( your zip ) when it's consumed in the production of another artifact ( your framework ), then you can use the dependency plugins' copy goal.  It allows you to specify new names for the dependencies that you are pulling into your build -- but note you aren't actually changing the maven coords, which, I believe, is something to be avoided like the plague.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This project would be something like a framework which should serve different zips (all developed using maven). The framework though has a common function. So at the time of building, it wouldn't actually know which zip or what are it's GAV. Hence I thought, the only possible way is to get them as system parameters (the zip will be there already in the local m2 repo) when the build runs.

Comment: If the zips are actually different, then they should be built in separate builds, then the framework will have a dependency on the one it once when it get's built.  IF the zips are actually one thing, then you shouldn't consider giving it different deployment coordinates.  If you need the name of the physical artifact to change, there are ways to acheive that.

Comment: Yes, the zips are different and they would be built in separate builds. My thought was, the framework will just have an example zip's dependency, with all co-ordinates as pom properties. When the framework gets built after the separate build of each zip, it would be provided with the zip's actual GAV as parameters, which would override the existing example and then the build would continue.

Comment: I sense this is going little crazy, any suggestions for ways to change the name of the physical artifact?

Comment: The dependency plugin's copy goal can be used to copy in specific artifacts.  Part of the configuration of that allows you to specify a new name for each dependency as it comes in.  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

Comment: You should accept the answer if it's helping you.  You could also edit your question to explain why you were wanting to dynamically name the artifacts, and then I'll add the dependency plugin stuff to the answer.  Enrich the community :)

Comment: Sorry, doing it now. I will update the question as well in some time.